# .NET Core Database Operation Failed when logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 applications:

1. ManagementStudio
2. DocumentStudio

DocumentStudio references ManagementStudio dlls. The account management function is located in ManagementStudio so if I want to login from DocumentStudio, its tied to one of the dlls within ManagementStudio.

Right now, this is the error I get when I try to login from DocumentStudio:

> A database operation failed while processing the request.
>   SqlException: Invalid object name 'ApplicationUsers'.  There are
>   pending model changes for ManagementStudioDbContext In Visual Studio,
>   use the Package Manager Console to scaffold a new migration for these
>   changes and apply them to the database:
>
> PM> Add-Migration [migration name]  PM> Update-Database Alternatively,
>   you can scaffold a new migration and apply it from a command prompt at
>   your project directory:
>
> > dotnet ef migrations add [migration name] 
> >     dotnet ef database update

Previously I have already run all migrations for ManagementStudio. However, I discovered that if I go back and add another migration, I'll suddenly have a bunch of Delete Data and Insert Data's of the same thing. As in, the data deleted and entered are the same.

When I perform the migration and update the database, the same error happens. I am unsure of how to solve this issue.

The structure of my database is like this:

There are 2 schemas. ManagementStudio.[Name] and DocumentStudio.[Name]

My Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DocumentStudioDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.DS_ConnectionString)));
    services.AddDbContext<ManagementStudioDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.DS_ConnectionString)));

    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
            = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();

    });

    var lockoutOptions = new LockoutOptions()
    {
        DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5,
    };

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUsers>(options => {
        options.Lockout = lockoutOptions;
    })
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ManagementStudioDbContext>();

    services.AddScoped<DbContext, DocumentStudioDbContext>();
    services.AddScoped<CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper<ApplicationUsers>>();
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
    });

    services.AddDataProtection()
        //.PersistKeysToFileSystem(KeyRingConfigurationManager.GetBasePath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CENTRAL_APPLICATION_SETTINGS")))
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(ResolvePaths.GetBasePathDI(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.CentralApplicationSettings), "KeyRing"))
        .SetApplicationName(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.DataProtectionApplicationName));

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        // Cookie settings
        options.Cookie.Name = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.CookieName);
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        options.Cookie.Path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.CookiePath);
        options.Cookie.Domain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.CookieDomain);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.CookieExpiryTimeSpanInMinutes)));

        options.LoginPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.LoginPath);
        options.AccessDeniedPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.AccessDeniedPath);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });


    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Comment: do u have one ConnectionString ? can u show it (in Startup.cs)

Comment: I have 2 connection strings in my Startup.cs but they are the same connection string.

Comment: I edited the question to show how its declare in my startup.cs

Comment: I don't understand why 2 and why none has IdentityUser as it is clear that the App is asking for Identity

Comment: I added my entire startup.cs. Not sure if its clearer. Im not using IdentityUser, Mine is called ApplicationUser

Comment: you need to be more clear about it . each project is just using different  table in the same DB Just different tables  ?

Comment: Both projects are using the same DB. They have their own schema. E.g. [ManagementStudio].ApplicationUsers. However, DocumentStudio is using the ApplicationUsers from ManagementStudio. thats why I included its DbContext in the startup.cs

Comment: https://hackingmonkeys.com/blog/2018-03-24/ef-core-multiple-db-contexts-schemas-and-projects

Comment: I realized what the previous image meant. When I recompiled and deleted and remigrated to my database, i forgot to push the new dlls to DocumentStudio. When I did that, it solved the migration versioning issue. However, I still cant login for some reason. I edited the question to show the error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use IdentityUser  please read the Doc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-user-data

Comment: My applicationuser extends IdentityUser